# How to do approxQuantile over window using Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window, quantile

I have a data set and I tried to find approxQuantile. It works for sample set but not with window function.

```
+------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
|original    |variation                             |similarity_score     |
+------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
|pencils     |pencils                               |0.982669767327994    |
|pencils     |pencils ticonderoga                   |0.8875609147113148   |
|pencils     |pencils bulk                          |0.5536876549778099   |
|pencils     |pencils for kids                      |0.39102614317876977  |
|pencils     |mechanical pencils                    |0.3837525124443511   |
|pencils     |school supplies                       |0.36800207529412093  |
|pencils     |pencils mechanical                    |0.20423055289450207  |
|pencils     |black pencils                         |0.08241323295822053  |
|pencils     |erasers                               |0.08101804016695552  |
|pencils     |papermate pencils                     |0.08091683972455012  |
|pencils     |pensils for kids                      |0.07299289422964994  |
|pencils     |loose leaf paper                      |0.07113136587149338  |
|pencils     |pencil sharpener                      |0.0684130629091813   |
|pencils     |pencils with sayings                  |0.06350472916694737  |
|pencils     |cute pencils                          |0.058316002229988215 |
|pencils     |colored pencils                       |0.05552992878175486  |
|pencils     |pensils sharpener                     |0.0491689934641725   |
|pencils     |pens                                  |0.048082618970934014 |
|pencils     |mechanical pencils 0.5                |0.04730075285308284  |
|pencils     |pencil box                            |0.04537707727651545  |
|pencils     |pencil case                           |0.04408623373105654  |
|pencils     |pensils 0.5                           |0.042054450870644036 |
|pencils     |crayons                               |0.03968021119078101  |
|pencils     |cool pencils                          |0.03952088726420226  |
|pencils     |pen                                   |0.037752562111173546 |
|pencils     |cool pensils                          |0.037510831184747497 |
|pencils     |glue sticks                           |0.032787653384488386 |
|pencils     |drawing pencils                       |0.032398405257143804 |
|pencils     |cute pensils                          |0.031057982991620214 |
|pencils     |cool penciles                         |0.02964868546657146  |
|pencils     |art pencils                           |0.027646328736291175 |
|pencils     |index cards                           |0.02744109743018355  |
|pencils     |folders                               |0.027070809949858353 |
|pencils     |pensil cases                          |0.0245633981485688   |
|pencils     |golf pencils                          |0.02411058428627058  |
|pencils     |notebooks                             |0.023534237276835582 |
|pencils     |binder                                |0.02262728927378412  |
|pencils     |pens bulk                             |0.021022196010267332 |
|pencils     |folders with pockets                  |0.020883099832185503 |
|pencils     |amazon basics pens                    |0.02010866875890696  |
|pencils     |notebook                              |0.02002518175509854  |
|pencils     |pencil grips                          |0.01712161261500511  |
|pencils     |scissors                              |0.014319987175720715 |
|pencils     |paper                                 |0.013844962316376306 |
|pencils     |tissues                               |0.012853953323240916 |
|pencils     |sketch book                           |0.011383006178195793 |
|pencils     |colored pens                          |0.010608837622836953 |
|pencils     |printer paper                         |0.007159662743211316 |
|pencils     |pencil holder                         |0.005219375924877335 |
|pencils     |copy paper                            |0.0048398059676751275|
|pencils     |paper clips                           |0.004323946307993657 |
|pencils     |backpack                              |0.002456516357354455 |
|pencils     |amazonbasics                          |0.002386583749856832 |
|pencils     |desk organizer                        |0.0014871301773208652|
|pencils     |fun penciles                          |7.114920197678272E-4 |
|pencils     |pensils crayola                       |5.863935694892475E-4 |
|pencils     |paper towels                          |4.956030568975998E-4 |
|pencils     |pensils usa                           |3.074806676441355E-4 |
|pencils     |golf pensils                          |1.6343203531543173E-4|
|pencils     |carpenter penciles                    |1.537148743666664E-4 |
|pencils     |usb extension cable                   |9.276356621610018E-5 |
|baby monitor|baby monitor m6s                      |0.9497291269175191   |
|baby monitor|baby monitor                          |0.9449706931157679   |
|baby monitor|baby monitor audio                    |0.9194544999991849   |
|baby monitor|baby monitor m7                       |0.6828123503685779   |
|baby monitor|video baby monitor                    |0.6587247331182673   |
|baby monitor|motorola baby monitor                 |0.4112370152461352   |
|baby monitor|wifi baby monitor                     |0.32615298083708877  |
|baby monitor|baby monitor with camera              |0.32488468999022607  |
|baby monitor|ibaby monitor m2                      |0.22209678642286393  |
|baby monitor|babybmonitor                          |0.22201449474747625  |
|baby monitor|baby monitor motorola                 |0.15539204748659272  |
|baby monitor|ibaby monitor wall mount              |0.15534317135388104  |
|baby monitor|baby monitor wifi                     |0.1452555652119229   |
|baby monitor|infant optics dxr-8 video baby monitor|0.1254649582976917   |
|baby monitor|babymonitor video                     |0.07508481508302599  |
|baby monitor|baby ping                             |0.07479584563204815  |
|baby monitor|summer baby monitor                   |0.06805384082762049  |
|baby monitor|arlo baby monitor                     |0.06026686625908922  |
|baby monitor|summer infant monitor                 |0.05179703845795807  |
|baby monitor|baby monitor                          |0.05132347606161915  |
|baby monitor|nanit baby monitor                    |0.05098268103975827  |
|baby monitor|owlet baby monitor                    |0.049905204987139684 |
|baby monitor|baby crib                             |0.04241570098880047  |
|baby monitor|cocoon cam                            |0.042065782030944146 |
|baby monitor|angelcare baby monitor                |0.03879796480510425  |
|baby monitor|nest camera indoor                    |0.03752577054574136  |
|baby monitor|hello baby monitor                    |0.036520838537481    |
|baby monitor|babysense video monitor               |0.03601327242576456  |
|baby monitor|lollipop monitor                      |0.03546663357189976  |
|baby monitor|baby                                  |0.03437681615854988  |
|baby monitor|baby breathing monitor                |0.029493224000661625 |
|baby monitor|baby doppler                          |0.02356697418340991  |
|baby monitor|baby gate                             |0.021958869140002453 |
|baby monitor|baby heartbeat monitor                |0.014386588623583382 |
|baby monitor|arlo                                  |0.013883004625408599 |
|baby monitor|security camera                       |0.013712142985200558 |
|baby monitor|arlo monitor                          |0.01047770092532903  |
|baby monitor|wyze cam                              |0.00661600182771142  |
|baby monitor|eufy babymonitor                      |0.004696950719180201 |
|baby monitor|yi home camera                        |0.004032626118694353 |
|baby monitor|monitor                               |0.0028295679527875124|
|baby monitor|baby registry                         |0.0027895987025737122|
|baby monitor|diaper genie                          |0.0026936137516863717|
|baby monitor|crib mattress                         |0.0022388567663420476|
+------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

When I tried -

```
val quantiles = df.filter($"original" === "baby monitor").stat.approxQuantile("similarity_score",
           Array(0.20,0.65),0.0)

val Q1 = quantiles(0)
val Q3 = quantiles(1)
val IQR = Q3 - Q1           

val lowerRange = Q1 - 1.5*IQR
val upperRange = Q3+ 1.5*IQR 

val outliers = df.filter($"original" === "baby monitor").filter(s"similarity_score < $lowerRange or similarity_score > $upperRange")
```

This gives

```
+------------+------------------------+-------------------+
|original    |variation               |similarity_score   |
+------------+------------------------+-------------------+
|baby monitor|baby monitor m6s        |0.9497291269175191 |
|baby monitor|baby monitor            |0.9449706931157679 |
|baby monitor|baby monitor audio      |0.9194544999991849 |
|baby monitor|baby monitor m7         |0.6828123503685779 |
|baby monitor|video baby monitor      |0.6587247331182673 |
|baby monitor|motorola baby monitor   |0.4112370152461352 |
|baby monitor|wifi baby monitor       |0.32615298083708877|
|baby monitor|baby monitor with camera|0.32488468999022607|
|baby monitor|ibaby monitor m2        |0.22209678642286393|
|baby monitor|babybmonitor            |0.22201449474747625|
+------------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

How do I do this using window function such that I perform the same for all the dataset based on original column :

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("original")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to compute percentile of a column on a window

```
val withPercentile = Seq( ("a",1),("b",2),("b",1)
              ).toDF("type","count");
    s.withColumn("perce", expr("percentile_approx(count,array(0.75, 0.5, 0.25)) over (partition by type) "))

withPercentile.show();
```

Comment: can you explain if this is same as my function ? Little confused

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do that idiomatically in Spark but if running multiple computations is not an issue you can

1. Collect all categories
2. Run computation for each category
3. Union results

```
df.select("original").distinct().collect().map { value =>
  // your code here
}.reduce(_ union _)
```